# How to group data by a related field as separate columns?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a dataset of survey responses like this:

| survey_id | user_id | question | answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | fav_colour | red |
| 1 | 2 | fav_colour | blue |
| 1 | 2 | fav_fruit | orange |
| 2 | 3 | fav_sport | hockey |

I want to be able to use a single query with a survey ID to query the rows by survey ID like so:

`...where survey_id = 1`

| survey_id | user_id | fav_color | fav_fruit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | red | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | blue | orange |

`...where survey_id = 2`

| survey_id | user_id | fav_sport |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | hockey |

How can I perform a query to get each question for a survey as a column, listing each response under it?

Answer (score 1):

**Table**:

```
create table survey(survey_id int ,user_id int,question varchar(20),answer varchar(20));
insert into survey values(1,1,'fav_colour','red'),(1,2,'fav_colour','blue'),(1,2,'fav_fruit','orange'),(2,3,'fav_sport','hockey');
```

**SQL for Full Display**:

```
WITH favcolor
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT survey_id,
                        user_id,
                        CASE
                          WHEN question = 'fav_colour' THEN answer
                        END AS fav_color
                 FROM   survey) inline_view
         WHERE  fav_color IS NOT NULL),
     favsport
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT survey_id,
                        user_id,
                        CASE
                          WHEN question = 'fav_sport' THEN answer
                        END AS fav_sport
                 FROM   survey) inline_view
         WHERE  fav_sport IS NOT NULL),
     favfruit
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT survey_id,
                        user_id,
                        CASE
                          WHEN question = 'fav_fruit' THEN answer
                        END AS fav_fruit
                 FROM   survey) inline_view
         WHERE  fav_fruit IS NOT NULL)
SELECT COALESCE(inline_view.survey_id, ff.survey_id) survey_id,
       COALESCE(inline_view.user_id, ff.user_id)     user_id,
       inline_view.fav_color,
       inline_view.fav_sport,
       ff.fav_fruit
FROM   (SELECT COALESCE(fc.survey_id, fs.survey_id) survey_id,
               COALESCE(fc.user_id, fs.user_id)     user_id,
               fc.fav_color,
               fs.fav_sport
        FROM   (SELECT survey_id,
                       user_id,
                       fav_color
                FROM   favcolor) fc
               FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT survey_id,
                                       user_id,
                                       fav_sport
                                FROM   favsport) fs
                            ON fc.survey_id = fs.survey_id
                               AND fc.user_id = fs.user_id) inline_view
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT survey_id,
                               user_id,
                               fav_fruit
                        FROM   favfruit) ff
                    ON inline_view.survey_id = ff.survey_id
                       AND inline_view.user_id = ff.user_id;
```

Output:

```
 survey_id | user_id | fav_color | fav_sport | fav_fruit
-----------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------
         1 |       1 | red       |           |
         1 |       2 | blue      |           | orange
         2 |       3 |           | hockey    |
(3 rows)
```

**SQL for particular id** , survey_id say 1 , the earlier SQL with filter on survery_id:

```
WITH favcolor
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT survey_id,
                        user_id,
                        CASE
                          WHEN question = 'fav_colour' THEN answer
                        END AS fav_color
                 FROM   survey) inline_view
         WHERE  fav_color IS NOT NULL),
     favsport
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT survey_id,
                        user_id,
                        CASE
                          WHEN question = 'fav_sport' THEN answer
                        END AS fav_sport
                 FROM   survey) inline_view
         WHERE  fav_sport IS NOT NULL),
     favfruit
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT survey_id,
                        user_id,
                        CASE
                          WHEN question = 'fav_fruit' THEN answer
                        END AS fav_fruit
                 FROM   survey) inline_view
         WHERE  fav_fruit IS NOT NULL)
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT COALESCE(inline_view.survey_id, ff.survey_id) survey_id,
               COALESCE(inline_view.user_id, ff.user_id)     user_id,
               inline_view.fav_color,
               inline_view.fav_sport,
               ff.fav_fruit
        FROM   (SELECT COALESCE(fc.survey_id, fs.survey_id) survey_id,
                       COALESCE(fc.user_id, fs.user_id)     user_id,
                       fc.fav_color,
                       fs.fav_sport
                FROM   (SELECT survey_id,
                               user_id,
                               fav_color
                        FROM   favcolor) fc
                       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT survey_id,
                                               user_id,
                                               fav_sport
                                        FROM   favsport) fs
                                    ON fc.survey_id = fs.survey_id
                                       AND fc.user_id = fs.user_id) inline_view
               FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT survey_id,
                                       user_id,
                                       fav_fruit
                                FROM   favfruit) ff
                            ON inline_view.survey_id = ff.survey_id
                               AND inline_view.user_id = ff.user_id)
       final_inline_view
WHERE  survey_id = 1 ;
```

Output:

```
survey_id | user_id | fav_color | fav_sport | fav_fruit
-----------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------
         1 |       1 | red       |           |
         1 |       2 | blue      |           | orange
(2 rows)
```

**For Survey_id=2**:

```
WITH favcolor
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT survey_id,
                        user_id,
                        CASE
                          WHEN question = 'fav_colour' THEN answer
                        END AS fav_color
                 FROM   survey) inline_view
         WHERE  fav_color IS NOT NULL),
     favsport
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT survey_id,
                        user_id,
                        CASE
                          WHEN question = 'fav_sport' THEN answer
                        END AS fav_sport
                 FROM   survey) inline_view
         WHERE  fav_sport IS NOT NULL),
     favfruit
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT survey_id,
                        user_id,
                        CASE
                          WHEN question = 'fav_fruit' THEN answer
                        END AS fav_fruit
                 FROM   survey) inline_view
         WHERE  fav_fruit IS NOT NULL)
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT COALESCE(inline_view.survey_id, ff.survey_id) survey_id,
               COALESCE(inline_view.user_id, ff.user_id)     user_id,
               inline_view.fav_color,
               inline_view.fav_sport,
               ff.fav_fruit
        FROM   (SELECT COALESCE(fc.survey_id, fs.survey_id) survey_id,
                       COALESCE(fc.user_id, fs.user_id)     user_id,
                       fc.fav_color,
                       fs.fav_sport
                FROM   (SELECT survey_id,
                               user_id,
                               fav_color
                        FROM   favcolor) fc
                       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT survey_id,
                                               user_id,
                                               fav_sport
                                        FROM   favsport) fs
                                    ON fc.survey_id = fs.survey_id
                                       AND fc.user_id = fs.user_id) inline_view
               FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT survey_id,
                                       user_id,
                                       fav_fruit
                                FROM   favfruit) ff
                            ON inline_view.survey_id = ff.survey_id
                               AND inline_view.user_id = ff.user_id)
       final_inline_view
WHERE  survey_id = 2 ;
```

Output:

```
 survey_id | user_id | fav_color | fav_sport | fav_fruit
-----------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------
         2 |       3 |           | hockey    |
(1 row)
```

Comment: Let me know if you want explanation for constructing the query. The logic is very simple even though the SQL is pretty long. There are repetitive pieces there.

Answer (score 0):

the tablefunc module contains function to do that:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tablefunc.html